# How to make an array of colors?

Tags: color

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[space]{ctex}
\begin{document}
\definecolorseries{mycolors}{rgb}{last}{red}{yellow}
\resetcolorseries[5]{mycolors} \newcommand{\M}{\rule{6mm}{0mm}\rule{0mm}{2mm}}
\newcommand{\R}{\colorbox{mycolors!!+}{\M}}
\R\R\R\R\R\R\\[9pt]
\resetcolorseries[5]{mycolors}
\color{mycolors!!+}AA,
\color{mycolors!!+}AA,
\color{mycolors!!+}AA,
\color{mycolors!!+}AA \\[9pt]
\resetcolorseries[5]{mycolors}
\textcolor{{mycolors!!++}{颜色，}
\textcolor{{mycolors!!++}{颜色，}
\textcolor{{mycolors!!++}{颜色，}
\textcolor{{mycolors!!++}{颜色} \\[9pt] \colorbox{mycolors!![0]}{\M}
\colorbox{mycolors!![3]}{\M} \colorbox{mycolors!![5]}{\M}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Your original question title was about why the above code doesn't compile. The problem is that you wrote `\textcolor{{mycolors!!++}{颜色，}` four times, but it should really be `\textcolor{mycolors!!++}{颜色，}`. Just remove the four superfluous opening curly brackets and the code should compile fine. (Wrapping up the problem in Chinese: 问题是：多了四个大括号。)